# iOS UINavigationController after setting background to transparent shows black screen

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, transparent

I got a really weird issue with `UINavigationController`. 
I am trying to present opaque `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController`and I want to see blurry previous controller content.
I set alpha to `UIViewController` view:

```
view.alpha = 0.9
```

Then I try to get rid of `UINavigationController` background:

```
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Initially during the `UINavigationController` animation transition everything looks fine, but after animation finishes `UINavigationController` background becomes black. This issue only exists if color is transparent.

Maybe someone else experienced this issue?

Comment: No, this issue is not related with UIViewController's content positioning inside navigation controller. I am specifically asking about setting navigationController background (and not navigationbar background).

Comment: For that, you should override UINavigationController and set the `backgroundColor` of its `view` in `awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are showing navigation controller modally try to set it's modalPresentationStyle to .overFullScreen

Comment: This partially solves my problem, however I would like not to use modalPresentationStyle. But I will figure it out. Thank you!